# How to make Ionic 4 build for a browser?

Tags: ionic-framework, browser, ionic4

I’m unfortunately having difficulty deploying my ionic project for web. No matter what I do, commands such as 'ionic build, ‘ionic build --prod’, ‘ng build --prod’, or whatsoever always create a www folder that is incorrect. The index.html in this www folder is always blank when viewed from a browser.

I’ve tested this issue on other ionic projects as well (just generated some from templates) and the same issue occurs here, with the index.html in the www folder always being displaying a blank site. If possible, I’d appreciate any help if that’s OK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
ionic cordova run browser
ionic cordova build browser --prod
```

For testing purpose use `ionic serve` . It will rebuild automatically every time when you update your code.

Comment: Ah this worked, thank you! Seems the issue was primarily with my server.js file & that I wasn't testing via ionic serve in the www folder

Answer (score 1):

have you changed the base href in index.html from

base href="/"
to

base href="."